# Bind - forward DNS Query

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, windows-dns

Gentlemans, this question is VIQ (Very Important Question :D )
Can BIND forward missing DNS query of an existing zone to Windows DNS server in same local network?
We need Active Directory ( and Active directory need DNS serwer ), but we don't want integrate AD with Bind or allow for zone transfer between Bind and Win DNS ( if this is possibile ).

DNS query route:
Client computer->dns query for "company.local"->Bind: If Bind don't have some entry in zone "company.local" forward query to Win DNS server

Can anyone help me with that? I dig all google and don't found answer
Thanks

Comment: BIND won't do this to the best of my knowledge.  However, dnsmasq will (not a great idea IMHO) - so depending on your particular requirements (for instance, if you're only using BIND for basic name resolution) and how badly you want to do this,  you might be able to replace BIND with dnsmasq.

Answer (score 2):

No, afaik BIND cannot be configured to do this.

Either way, it seems like asking for trouble to set up a new zone (Active Directory or otherwise) with the same name as an already existing zone. If you simply use different names, eg `foo.example.com` to go along with `example.com` (or completely unrelated names if that is preferable), normal delegations will work.

Also, the `local` TLD is reserved for mdns use. Use your own, actually registered, domain name(s).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think that i don't have choice and i will create a new zone only for AD (that doesn't exist on bind) nad use forwarding from bind to windows DNS